# What are the pros and cons of skipping some member variable initialization in c++?

Tags: c++, constructor, member-variables

Consider the following example,

Aclass.h

```
class Aclass()
{
private: 
   int something;
   double nothing;
};
```

Aclass.cpp

```
#include "Aclass.h"

Aclass::Aclass (int x) {
    something = x;
    nothing = y;
}
//Write some functions to manipulate x and y.
```

So now, what is the difference if I skip initializing `y` in the constructor? What is the downside and how does it affect the remainder of the code? Is this a good way to code? What I know is that a constructor will create an object anyway whether `x` and `y` are initialized or even if both are not (default constructor) and constructors are used to create versatile objects.

Comment: Did you mean `nothing` instead `y`?

Comment: Strictly speaking this is not initialisation, that would be in the initialiser list `Aclass::Aclass(int x) : something (x) {}`

Comment: And why the `()` after the class name?

Answer (score 4):

If there is no reason to initialize a variable, you don´t need this variable
=> Delete it entirely. Seriously, an uninitialized var is good for...? Nothing. (only for initializing it).

If you plan to initialize it later before it is used:
Can you guarantee that it will get a value before it is first read from, independent of how often and in what order the class methods are called? Then it´s not "wrong", but instead of tediously checking that (and risking bugs because it´s complicated), it´s far more easy to give it a value in the constructor.

No, making it more complicated on purpose is not a good way to code.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving any variable uninitialized will allow it to acquire some garbage value.

Result = **Undefined Behaviour**. And it has no pros.

Comment: If you don't explicitly initialize an object, the default constructor is called, giving you a well-formed object. For example, `class C { std::string s;}` will print `0` when you type `C c; std::cout << c.s.length() << std::endl;`.